# Sitecore 8.2 Update 4 in Azure SQL

Tags: azure

Sitecore 8.2 Update 4

I am looking to run Sitecore in IaaS. Azure VMs for web and Azure SQL for database. Not the new Azure service stack.

Its great that Sitecore comes with dacpac files in all installations now. In the /Databases/dacpac folder, in the Sitecore installation zip. But when I try to import Sitecore's dacpac files into an Azure data I get errors.

> Error encountered during the service operation. 
>       Cannot create a BACPAC from a file that does not contain exported data.

So I thought I would just create new dacpac files and try that. When I try and create new dacpac file, by exporting data tier in SQL Management Studio, I get errors on every database.

[image]

I am starting to think I have to use the Azure toolkit to do this even though I don't want to use the Azure service stack at all.

Comment: I have previously installed sitecore in my local. Created bacpac file and then restored it in to azure sql. Used Ssms 2016 as it is easy to import and export bacpac in that. You can try this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got around this was not to use the dacpac files from Sitecore. From what I read dacpac only contain schema where bacpac contain schema and data.

In my scenario I was using SQL 2014, not sure how much that matters. But I was not able to create a bacpac file out of my Sitecore 8.2 U4 databases. To fix that, I installed the latest SSMS package.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

After that, I was able to `Export Data-Tier Application` on core, master, web and reporting. Creating my bacpac files. Then I was able to `Import Data-Tier Application` into my Azure instance. I could also use the import tool in Azure.

I wonder what the dacpac files in the Sitecore zip are for.

Comment: In future, for what it's worth, I've always used the SQL Database Migration Wizard https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/